# MYSQL select tag associated id's from same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have a MYSQL table which stores a load of tags that are associated to one another like so:

```
id  level   upper_tag   value
----------------------------------------------
1   0       0           Electric
2   0       0           Home
3   1       2           Gas Cooker
4   1       1           wire
5   2       4           superconductor_wire
6   0       0           Sexy stuff
7   2       3           cleaner
8   0       0           Sport
9   1       8           trainers
10  1       8           rugby
11  2       10          Nike
```

Basically I need to find the associated tags so if I call sport I want the tags: Sport, trainers, rugby and nike returned. If I chose the tag rugby I would get back rugby and nike.

I have had a think and am not sure if I am on the right lines as I am a MYSQL noob. here is my attempt but it does not give me the right answer:

```
SELECT * FROM tag t
WHERE  t.`id` = (SELECT `upper_tag` FROM tag) AND t.`id` = 8
;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4550/2)

Comment: `SELECT upper_tag FROM tag` Will give you bunch of ids and you can't compare like that. You have to compare with only on id.

Comment: You need a rather complicated solution. You cannot, without additional code, traverse multiple levels of relations.  There is a solution here though:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091457/get-all-children-by-parent-in-mysql-query

Comment: I guess that will be better than making loads of mini queries

Comment: @bubblebath Can you please provide schema for this table on sqlfilddle http://sqlfiddle.com/. If there are going to be 'n' number if tags for given value then you need a stored procedure

Comment: Php code will be a lot slower than MYSQL surely

Comment: Added sqlfiddle for my table

Comment: @bubblebath , please add data too in sqlfiddle

Comment: Added to data to sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a Nested set model - read through the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model#Example) article and see the example on how left/right values are assigned. Once you have those two columns added and indexed correctly, your queries will be as simple as

```
SELECT t.* FROM tag t
WHERE t.`left` >= X and t.`right` <= Y
```

Where `X` is the 'left' value and `Y` is the 'right' value of 'Sport' tag

You can combine the lookup an actual loading into one query

```
SELECT t.* FROM tag t
JOIN tag t ON t.`left` >= b.`left` AND t.`right` <= b.`right`
WHERE b.id = 8
```

Howerver you would need extra work to maintain (reindex as necessary) the integrity of these left/right values whenever you add/remove/move any tag.

Answer (score 0):

if you want it across all levels, you need to use joins and unions. add one join per query for each deeper level.

```
select * from
(
select t1.id as parent, t2.* from tag t1 
inner join tag t2 on t1.id=t2.parent_id 
union
select t1.id as parent, t3.* from tag t1 
inner join tag t2 on t1.id=t2.parent_id 
inner join tag t3 on t2.id=t3.parent_id 
) tag where tag.parent=1
```

Comment: This is not right as I will know the ID so I want the select ID '8' and I want to to basically recursively search down showing all the tags that have an upper_tag that eventually ends up with the searched for tag. If I select ID 8 this wont return- trainers, rugby and nike

Comment: ah, you also need nike? you will need to do a lot of self joins.

Comment: it could be infinite sub joins though

Comment: that's the pitfall of the EAV data model, you need to join from one level to the next. Perhaps you should not be using SQL for this. Alternative is to add 'main parent' column if speed is a concern

Comment: the query above could be re-written and optimised in many ways, but you will still need a join per level.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tag t WHERE t.upper_tag=8 OR t.id=8
```

this should give you all tag with the value upper_tag=8 and id = 8

sport=8, rugby=upper_tag 8, trainer=upper_tag 8

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT *  
from tag AS t 
WHERE (t.upper_tag IN(SELECT id  from tag WHERE upper_tag=8))
  OR (t.id = 8) OR (t.upper_tag = 8)
```

Comment: If I add another tag to Nike (which could happen) then it fails :(