# Mysql Function returns limited characters even using LONGTEXT

Tags: php, mysql, function

I'm having a Function in Mysql which returns very long result(concat of multiple ids). The result is actually having more than 1000 characters. But mysql returns only limited characters and trimmed the remaining.
I have used LONGTEXT as the variable datatype and still same result. 
What should I do to get the complete result ? the character limit of my result may go bigger than in future.

Here you see the function I'm using, the result is concat of id's, in my case I have 1000's of id:
[Get all children by parent in mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091457/get-all-children-by-parent-in-mysql-query)

Comment: Use ultralongtext datatype of course. No, seriously, how do you think we can help without seeing the function?

Comment: You should probably redesign your database so that you get back a result set with one ID per row. Returning huge strings of concatenated IDs is generally a sign that you've doing it wrong.

Comment: Also, what Matt said.

Comment: Are you using GROUP BY statement ?

Comment: @fancyPants Updated my question with the Function details, pls check

Comment: @Suren: How are you framing the return text? By a `group concat`? If yes, that has some length constraints. If no, what is the data type of variable into which return value is assigned. Is that too a `longtext` or not?

Comment: @Ravinder, yes i'm framing return text using CONCAT and data type of variable is long text.What is the constraints in concat please explain.

Comment: @Ravinder, Yes there was a constraint in GROUP CONCAT,I set the max length using this SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000; and it is working correctly now.. Is that ok ? or I need to do any improvements in the Function ?

Comment: @Suren: If it resolved the issue due to change of a session variable, then you need to set it on every call to the function. Better you make it in the function itself.

Comment: Ravinder, Thanks for the help, yes I set the session in function itself.